virt-manager / libvirt: user session starts at first login on host instead of at boot
I have a debian-based host with a few VMs that were set up in a virt-manager user session for better security: in case someone breaks out of the VM, they won't immediately have root access.
Network is set up so the VMs can be reached from, outside the host.
Now, I noticed that none of the VMs is accessible before I login locally on the host. It looks like the whole user-session is not started before this first host login. It does not necessarily have to be a login to the desktop, console is sufficient. And I don't have to start anything manually. Right after login, everything just starts. At least, the session and the VMs keep running when I log out.
Is there a way to start the libvirt user session when the host boots (or even better: a few minutes after boot)?
Secondary question: How does that even work? How does libvirt know when the user logs in?

I suspect that it is not actually libvirt user session in itself – instead the libvirt daemons run as part of the systemd user-level service manager, which is started alongside

Is there a way to start the libvirt user session when the host boots (or even better: a few minutes after boot)?

Run loginctl enable-linger <username> to have the systemd --user service manager start on boot for that user.
Use systemctl --user -t service to find the services that cause the VMs to start; disable them (move them to a different .target) and create a systemd .timer that starts them a bit later.

Secondary question: How does that even work? How does libvirt know when the user logs in?

If libvirt is started as a user service, then it doesn't care – it starts when it starts.
The login procedure calls various PAM modules via /etc/pam.d, some of which are responsible for various aspects of "session setup" (like setting environment variables or displaying the /etc/motd). One of them is pam_systemd, which informs the systemd-logind service about a new user session, and logind starts or stops user@<uid>.service (your user-level service manager) accordingly.

I could not find any matching services using systemd --user -t service. Only the system has libvirt-guests.service (active, exited) and libvirtd.service (active, running) that seens to take care of all sessions. When I check using the virtual machine manager GUI application, my VMs are in the section QEMU/KVM user session. I won't be on location  before next wednesday, but then I'll try the linger option.

It's certainly possible that it works differently now, but the last time I tried to use it, "user session" definitely spawned a separate set of daemons all running under the same account. Try to take a look at systemd-cgls or systemctl status -- -.slice and find your QEMU process within that tree.

Found it. There are indeed two related processes: /usr/sbin/libvirtd and /usr/sbin/virtlogd plus one qemu process per VM. I just could not find a service that I can start. If I understand correctly, this is what I would need to create a timer.

correction: ... cannot find a "user" service I can start ...
When I'm on location next time I log in as root first and check the status of the "system" libvirtd service

Which cgroup do they belong to? i.e. what does cat /proc/PID/cgroup or systemctl status PID / systemctl --user status PID report about each of them?

The libvirtd service belongs to the "system.slice" CGroup, while the libvirtd processes belong to the "user-1000.slice/session-2.scope"
